Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "_flutter.listViews: (-32000) Service connection disposed"
I'm new with Flutter.
I can launch my application on Chrome, but I can't launch it on the iOS simulator.
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "_flutter.listViews: (-32000) Service connection disposed".

My configuration
Flutter 3.24.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 80c2e84975 (il y a 4 semaines) • 2024-07-30 23:06:49 +0700
Engine • revision b8800d88be
Tools • Dart 3.5.0 • DevTools 2.37.2

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

UnInstall app from your phone/Simulator it will fix.
